# FunctionExpand vs FullSimplify

Tags: core-language

The documentation (v.11.3) says: "`FunctionExpand` is automatically called by `FullSimplify`."

Why then does `FullSimplify@FactorialPower[n,2]` produce `FactorialPower[n, 2]` instead of the simpler result produced by `FunctionExpand`?

Comment: `FullSimplify` will call `FunctionExapand` along with _many_ other routines. It picks the ‘best’ result based on the `ComplexityFunction` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `FunctionExpand` is not simpler:

```
FactorialPower[n, 2] // LeafCount
(* 3 *)
FactorialPower[n, 2] // FunctionExpand // LeafCount
(* 5 *)
```

`LeafCount` isn't the whole story, but it's the main thing `FullSimplify` looks at. You may, of course, attempt to formulate a `ComplexityFunction` that captures your notion of complexity.

Comment: So to understand why `FactorialPower[n, 2] // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify`
is not `FactorialPower[n, 2] // FullSimplify` despite the claim that `FunctionExpand` was called in the latter, I should understand it as having compared the two expressions for a `LeafCount` in the latter but not the former (where it never considered the equivalence).  Do I have that right?

Comment: I don't think `FullSimplify` knows a way to re-compact the expanded function here. So, in the case of `FactorialPower[n, 2] // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify`, it never sees the form with the lower leaf count.